# C#: Best optimized way for reading contents of a JS and CSS files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

Using **`C#, Framework 2.0`**

> What is the best optimized way for reading contents of a JS and CSS files?

*Note that the contents needs to write out at the same time*

### EDIT:

To be more clear, while loading the page I need to read all my JS file's contents and write out the contents on a page. Finally this page will act as a single JS file and in the same way for CSS files too.

Since here i am requesting to read the contents of a file number of times.

I am looking for the best way to optimize the performance of it while accessing the file.

Comment: Very unclear question, no background information

Comment: Optimized for what? There are a lot of parameters you can optimize for.

Comment: More info, please. You talk about pages, but I'm not sure. Write up some pseudo about how you want things to look from the clients perspective

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is the best way to read the contents of a file,

Use `File.ReadAllText(filepath)` to get the contents of it.

```
filepath = Server.MapPath(jsFile);
if (File.Exists(filepath))
{
   contents = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
   Response.Write(contents);
}
```

Comment: Since you don´t stated any special processing requirements js and css files can be handled as plain txt files. ReadAllText is not the best solution for very large files. Though i doubt your js or css touch that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of project, but you can take a look at [Bundling & Minification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx). That way you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal? Scan and output? Here's a version that is encoding-safe (ie: does encoding translation when possible)

```
    void ConcatenateAllSafe(StreamWriter output, params string[] files)
    {
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            using(StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line = null;
                while (null != (line = rd.ReadLine()))
                {
                    output.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This version will assume everything is sharing the same encoding
    void ConcatenateAllUnsafe(Stream output, params string[] files)
    {
        var data = new byte[1024 * 64];//64k should be enough for anyone

        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            using (Stream inStream = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                for (int offset = 0,
                         read; 0 != (read = inStream.Read(data, offset, data.Length)); offset += read)
                {
                    output.Write(data, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a ToolkitScriptManager, which will bundle, minify & compress all your javascripts into one request. You may try taking a look into this.

I understand your reason to bundle, minify & compress the javascript and CSS into one file, but fails to understand why it has to be done for every requests. You can either,

1. Use one of the existing Bundling and Minification tool as suggested by [CodeMaster in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11341263/30594) (YUICompressor, Closure Compiler, AJAXminifier). This would bundle the scripts and CSS only once, that too during build time itself and uses that to serve all the requests. To me this is the most effective way to bundle the scripts and reduces the load on server as they are simply static files and not processing is required for bundling them. Also, the scripts can be treated as static files and be cached at clients or loaded from CDN.
2. Use Toolkit Script Manager approach, where the custom handler would look for the query string, Look in its cache if the combination is present, if not build the output using [Florion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11341387/30594) and cache it for subsequent calls. By this way, you can avoid frequent file reads.